# Renaming model breakes migration history

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I have two models in two different apps:

```
# app1 models.py
class App1Model(models.Model):
    pass


# app2 models.py
from app1.models import App1Model

class App2Model(App1Model):
    pass
```

And I want to rename App1Model and then recreate App2Model to have explicit `OneToOneField` instead of magic `app1model_ptr`. So I create migration which deletes App2Model completely (I don't care about data because whatever reason), it runs successfully. Then I create migration in first app which renames App1Model and it runs perfect too, I check this table with new name and all it's relationships (and to it too), it's fine.

And then weird thing happens: when I run `makemigrations` or `migrate` on app2 I get an error

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'app2.App2Model'>]
```

It fails while creating current project state on very first migration of app2 (0001_initial.py in app2 migrations) where this model was created first time by inheriting from App1Model with its old name.
Is there some way of fixing this? In current state `App2Model` already deleted, `App1Model` renamed and I can't do anything with migrations on app2 because of this issue.

P.S. I use Django 1.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found solution:

Need to add last migration of `app2` where I deleted `App2Model` as dependency to migration of `app1` where I renamed `App1Model` so project state will be built in correct order. Actually error message itself has something related to it but I failed to catch the point:

> This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with
>   migrations (e.g. contrib.auth) in an app with no migrations; see
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#dependencies
>   for more

I put it here for future me and for those who will suffer from similar thing.